# WiX Overcoming "Could not access network location" error

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

Currently doing my best to put together an installer for our C# app using Wix but have hit a block with the following problem.

By default the application is installed in the ProgramFilesFolder however the installer allows a user to specify a custom installation directory/folder overriding the default location. The problem I am encountering is when the installation folder is deleted from the system running the installer fails with a "Could not access network location" message when ideally I'd like it to commence with a "repair" or "reinstall".

The user can't proceed past this message preventing them from uninstalling, installing or running a repair. The user can't proceed in any way past this message.

The following is the Wix code I am using:

```
<!-- Obtaining the installation directory from the registry -->
<Property Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
      <RegistrySearch Id="RegistrySearchAppFolder" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" 
                      Win64="no" Key="Software\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)"
                      Name="install_location" />
</Property>

<!-- Setup the main folders -->
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProductName)" />        
      </Directory>
</Directory>
```

How can I deal with this scenario in a graceful manner? Perhaps I am not using the correct code, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you use any custom actions? Did you run installation from a network location? Look in the system log for more details on the error or run uninstall with msi logging. It will help you understand what installer tries to access.